# Home app icon is not showing up properly on my iphone 6 device. It is completely black

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

The home app icon is not showing any of my images from xcassets. It only shows a black background.

So far, I've tried cleaning and rebuilding after deleting the app on my device. I've tried uploading different images with the same effect. I've also tried adding the icon files directly into the plist with the same effect.
[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjcw8.jpg)

[Link to xcassets img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alhbm.png)

Sorry, due to my low reputation, I was neither able to upload images nor post more than 2 links. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Showing some code might be useful.

Comment: I didn't use any code to add the images. I pretty much just did a drag and drop into the AppIcon xcassets file. There are no error/warning messages at all. Everything runs fine. The only thing is that the home screen icon is completely black.

Comment: Make sure that all the demensions are correct for the iphone 6.  Does it work on other devices?

Comment: I've tried it on my device and an iphone 5 simulator as well. Both behave exactly the same way. The app works as expected except for the app icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete your previous Appicon image set and create a new one.
In Images.xcassets press the "+" -> "App icons and launch images" -> "New iOS App icon". Then add your images with the right sizes(very important to have the exact right sizes). Make your images png format.

Look at this guide to get the right sizes: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Hope this helps.

Edit:

From the iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s
>   boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use
>   transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can
>   appear to float on a dark background, which tends to look especially
>   unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

Comment: Followed your instructions with no success unfortunately. I'm thinking that the icon is transparent per your suggestion. What's the easiest way to find out if an icon is transparent? All I can see is a gray background behind the icon.

Comment: Open up the image in your favorite photo editing program(photoshop) and remove the transparent background.